Running the Pycharm Debugger with a Docker/Django/Notebook setup?
I feel like I am missing some foundational truth about how Pycharm works, so I wanted to lay out how I develop and what I'm looking for.
I'm running a SvelteJS project with a Django backend. I usually work in Docker containers with the following compose file:
version: "3.6"
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.3
    platform: linux/amd64
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: <PASSWORD>
      MYSQL_DATABASE: <DATABASE>
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
  api:
    build: ./api
    restart: always
    image: myproject:latest
    env_file:
      - api/.env
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings.development
    ports:
       - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./api:/api
    command: bash -c "python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver_plus --threaded 0.0.0.0:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db:db

  web-svelte:
    build: ./svelte-frontend
    command: bash -c "npm install && npm run dev -- --host"
    ports:
      - "5173:5173"
    volumes:
      - ./svelte-frontend:/svelte-frontend
    depends_on:
      - "api"
  notebook:
    build: ./notebook
    command: python manage.py shell_plus --notebook
    env_file:
      - api/.env
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings.development
    volumes:
      - ./notebook:/api/notebooks
      - ./api:/api
    ports:
      - "8990:8990"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - api
    links:
      - db:db
volumes:
  dbdata:

Because my project is so backend heavy, I typically work with a set of Jupyter Notebooks that have all of my objects created and I run backend code manually that way to test it. I want to be able to drop breakpoints into Pycharm, run my notebook, and stop execution to observe the variables.
I've successfully created a Remote interpreter in Pycharm (I tried both Docker and Docker-Compose), but I can't seem to get execution to stop. I assume that is because my Notebook container is running a separate version of the Django server.

Also, I don't quite understand. Should I be launching my containers with my usual docker-compose commands, or through Pycharm's "run" buttons?
Can I get the workflow that I'm looking for?
